# Работа с файлами. Назначение FileWriter PrintWriter

Tags: java, файлы, filewriter

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите где можно почитать про следующие записи, я просто внятной информации не нашел либо не совсем понял прочитанное.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Если не сложно то объясните вкратце расскажите и зачем используется такая запись. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Такая запись дает вам возможность читать из файла построчно. Класс `FileReader` предоставляет возможность читать по 1 символу за раз, либо прочитать массив символов. Иногда это не удобно.

Допустим вы не знаете сколько символов в строке (их может быть разное количество), но вам надо прочитать все строки по отдельности.

В этом случае вам поможет `BufferedReader`. Он оборачивает `Reader` (`FileReader` в данном случае) и добавляет метод `readLine`, которым вы можете прочитать 1 целую строку (определение начала и конца строки `BufferedReader` возьмет на себя).

---

```
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
```

В отношении этого союза, могу сказать только одно, чем сам пользовался.

`FileWriter` дает возможность писать `int`, `char` (и их массивы) + `String` и `CharSequence`.

`PrintWriter` - оборачивает любой `Writer` и дает возможность писать туда объекты, внутри вызывает `String.valueOf` на них.

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (lock) {
        print(s);
        println();
    }
}
```

так же дает возможность писать форматированный вывод

```
public PrintWriter printf(String format, Object ... args) {
    return format(format, args);
}
```

В общем им можете пользоваться так же как `System.out`, т.к. `System.out` это объект класса `PrintWriter`